# rake db:migrate got rake aborted

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I study rails from a demo,
the original `database.yml` is

```
development:
adapter: sqlite3
database: db/development.sqlite3
pool: 5
timeout: 5000
```

so this demo use `sqlite` as database,but I want to change to `mysql`,so I change `database.yml` as:

```
adapter: mysql2
database: jobs_test
server: localhost
username: root
password: "1234"
pool: 5
timeout: 5000
encoding: utf8
```

when I run

```
rake db:migrate
```

then I got the error:

```
rake aborted!
Please install the sqlite3 adapter: `gem install activerecord-sqlite3-adapter`  
(sqlite3 is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.)
```

so,I have changed the adapter to `mysql2`,why it let me install `sqlite3 adapter`?

Comment: try `bundle update` first.

Comment: Can you post your Gemfile

Comment: thanks, I should `bundle update` first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your database.yml is indented properly with the config values nested under `development:` like this:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: jobs_test
  server: localhost
  username: root
  password: "1234"
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  encoding: utf8
```

You original example doesn't show proper indentation.

And of course if you haven't done so already, make sure to add:

```
gem 'mysql2'
```

to Gemfile and run:

```
bundle install
rake db:migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you remove or just update your test and production configurations in database.yml?